# How to apply same method to two different frames, containing different widgets, in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, methods

I am making a cricket game where there is an option to select two teams for the match. The user can select two teams from all available teams by clicking the next and previous buttons that change the image (actually the team's flag) and the team's name on every click. I have created a common function for the selection process. In that function/method, the labels and buttons are already present and packed. I only have to call it for team 1 and team 2 separately, by passing the allotted frames as an argument in the function.

Now the problem is, after calling that function for the first side (Team1), when I call it for the second side (Team 2), the images and names are only changed for the second side.
The problem can be better understood by looking at the program because maybe I am unable to explain my issue.
I want both pairs of next and previous buttons to work independently for the selection of teams. I have tried to make a separate class for this thing, but that's totally an irrelevant solution and of course is not working.

The piece of my code, extracted from my complete game code, is attached below.

```
from tkinter import *

class CricketMatch(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CricketMatch, self).__init__()

        self.title("Cricket 2020")
        self.geometry('980x660+200-60')
        self.state('zoomed')

        selection_Frame = Frame(self)
        selection_Frame.pack()

        ### TEAM 1 CONTAINER ###
        Team1_Container = Frame(selection_Frame)
        Team1_Container.pack(side = LEFT)

        ButtonFrame = Frame(Team1_Container)
        self.select_Teams(Team1_Container, ButtonFrame)   #Function called for team1
        ButtonFrame.pack(pady = (20,0))

        vsLabel = Label(selection_Frame, text = 'VS')
        vsLabel.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 50)

        # ### TEAM 2 CONTAINER ###
        Team2_Container = Frame(selection_Frame)
        Team2_Container.pack()

        ButtonFrame2 = Frame(Team2_Container)
        self.select_Teams(Team2_Container, ButtonFrame2)   #Function called for team2
        ButtonFrame2.pack(pady = (20,0))

    def select_Teams(self, ImageFrame, ButtonFrame):
        self.teams = ['Afghanistan', 'Australia', 'Bangladesh', 'England', 'India',
                    'Ireland', 'Kenya', 'Netherlands', 'Newzealand', 'Pakistan',
                    'Scotland', 'SouthAfrica', 'Srilanka', 'UAE', 'WestIndies',
                    'Zimbabwe']
        self.cur_image = 0

        self.image = Label(ImageFrame, text = f"{self.teams[self.cur_image]}.png" , font=('', 12, 'bold'), bg='light blue')
        self.image.pack(ipady = 30)

        self.left = Button(ButtonFrame, text="<", fg='red', font=('', 11, 'bold'), command=self.lefttoggle)
        self.left.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.image_name=Label(ButtonFrame, text=self.teams[self.cur_image], font=('', 10,'bold'))
        self.image_name.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.right = Button(ButtonFrame, text=">", fg='red', font=('', 11, 'bold'), command=self.righttoggle)
        self.right.pack(side=LEFT)

    def lefttoggle(self):
        self.cur_image = (self.cur_image - 1) % len(self.teams)
        self.update_image()

    def righttoggle(self):
        self.cur_image = (self.cur_image + 1) % len(self.teams)
        self.update_image()

    def update_image(self):
        self.image.config(text=f"{self.teams[self.cur_image]}.png")
        self.image_name.config(text=self.teams[self.cur_image])


Match = CricketMatch()
Match.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are you doing a modulo operation on self.cur_image

Comment: @reece To bring the next and previous images in a continous manner when button are pressed. Is there another way for it also? Actually I have edited another piece of code from somewhere else for this thing.

Comment: @reece If there is a better approach to do all this stuff then please share. I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: no I was just wondering because its not anything I've seen before to wrap round an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used same set of instance variables for the two team selections, they will be effective to the second team selection.

You should encapsulate the team selection in a class:

```py
class TeamSelector(Frame):
    teams = ['Afghanistan', 'Australia', 'Bangladesh', 'England', 'India',
             'Ireland', 'Kenya', 'Netherlands', 'Newzealand', 'Pakistan',
             'Scotland', 'SouthAfrica', 'Srilanka', 'UAE', 'WestIndies',
             'Zimbabwe']

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kw)
        self.cur_image = 0

        self.image = Label(self, text=f"{self.teams[self.cur_image]}.png", font=('', 12, 'bold'), bg='light blue')
        self.image.pack(ipady=30, fill=X)

        btn_frame = Frame(self)
        btn_frame.pack(pady=(20,0))

        self.left = Button(btn_frame, text="<", fg='red', font=('', 11, 'bold'), command=self.left_toggle)
        self.left.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.image_name = Label(btn_frame, text=self.teams[self.cur_image], font=('', 10,'bold'), width=20)
        self.image_name.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.right = Button(btn_frame, text=">", fg='red', font=('', 11, 'bold'), command=self.right_toggle)
        self.right.pack(side=LEFT)

    def left_toggle(self):
        self.cur_image = (self.cur_image - 1) % len(self.teams)
        self.update_image()

    def right_toggle(self):
        self.cur_image = (self.cur_image + 1) % len(self.teams)
        self.update_image()

    def update_image(self):
        self.image.config(text=f"{self.teams[self.cur_image]}.png")
        self.image_name.config(text=self.teams[self.cur_image])
```

Then use this class to create instances for team 1 and team 2 selections:

```py
class CricketMatch(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Cricket 2020")
        self.geometry('980x660+200-60')
        self.state('zoomed')

        selection_Frame = Frame(self)
        selection_Frame.pack()

        ### TEAM 1 SELECTOR ###
        self.team1 = TeamSelector(selection_Frame)
        self.team1.pack(side=LEFT)

        vsLabel = Label(selection_Frame, text = 'VS')
        vsLabel.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50)

        ### TEAM 2 SELECTOR ###
        self.team2 = TeamSelector(selection_Frame)
        self.team2.pack()
```